# How to get the ImageView that was being click by user inside an Array?

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview, onclicklistener

in Android Studio I developed a view that consist of 15 TableRows, and each TableRow contains 15 ImageViews. (Each ImageView store a Bitmap with square shape, and this produce a 15 x 15 square matrix). Relevant coding of View onCreate roughly as below:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[15];

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    tr[i] = new TableRow(this);

    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jmpty);
        imageViews[j] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViews[j].setImageBitmap(bmp); 
        imageViews[j].setOnClickListener(new doSomething()); 

        tr[i].addView(imageViews[j],oParams);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tr[i]);
}
....
```

My question is how do I know which imageView (Total = 15 x 15 = 225) was being clicked by user by utilizing OnClick event? i.e. If the user click the ImageView located at (imageViews[13] located at TableRow=4), can I return capture this x-y coordinate information (e.g. x=13, y=4) and return to other parts of program?

```
private class doSomething implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
        ......
        // what I want:
        int x = iv.GetImageViewNumber();    // how can I do this???
        int y = iv.GetTableRowNumber();    // how can I do this???
```

Or is there any other better alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class who inherits from ImageView, and inside this class create 2 attributes *int x* and *int y*, So when `onClickListener` is called you should cast the `View` to your custom class.

**Example:**

```
public calss MyCustomImageView extends ImageView{
   public int x;
   public int y;
}
```

---

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[15];

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    tr[i] = new TableRow(this);

    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jmpty);
        imageViews[j] = new MyCustomImageView(this);
        imageViews[j].setImageBitmap(bmp); 
        imageViews[j].setOnClickListener(new doSomething());
        imageViews[j].x = i;
        imageViews[j].y = j;

        tr[i].addView(imageViews[j],oParams);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tr[i]);
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  MyCustomImageView iv = (MyCustomImageView) v;

  int x = iv.x;
  int y = iv.y;

}
```

I hope it will help you, sorry for my English I'm beginner!

Answer (score 0):

to know which imageview has been clicked, you need to identify that view by its `ID` or `Tag`. You need to set it in your for loop and then get it when u want to identify in onClick method.

```
String tagString = "Image";
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
tr[i] = new TableRow(this);

    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jmpty);
        imageViews[j] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViews[j].setImageBitmap(bmp); 

        //setting image tag for each image in "Image1", "Image2"... format
        imageViews[j].setTag(tagString+j); 

        imageViews[j].setOnClickListener(new doSomething()); 

        tr[i].addView(imageViews[j],oParams);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tr[i]);
}
```

Identify the image in your onClick method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

 Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked items is "+v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;

}
```